# How to search for comma separated multiple values

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a table in MySQL in which a "skill" field has multiple comma-separated values, for instance: "PHP, JavaScript, C#".

I want to know an SQL query which will go through all values and give back a result according to the search values.

Comment: Read about mysql function FIELD_IN_SET

Comment: Or fix your database design.

Answer (score 0):

The correct MySQL function is `FIND_IN_SET()`.

You would use it like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE FIND_IN_SET('PHP', skill)>0
```

Where you can swap PHP out for the string you are searching for. This isn't the most efficient way to organize this data, but for smaller data sets might be fine.